# Split DataFrame every x unique values into new Dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, unique, slice

I need to slice a long format DataFrame by every x unique values for the purpose of visualizing. My actual dataset has ~ 90 variables for 20 individuals so I would like to split into 9 separate df's containing the entries for all 20 individuals for each variable.

I have created this simple example to help explain:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4],
                'Period':[1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,],
                'Food':['Ham','Ham','Ham','Cheese','Cheese','Cheese','Egg','Egg','Egg','Bacon','Bacon','Bacon',]})
df

''' ******* PSUEDOCODE *******
    df1 = unique entries [:2]
    df2 = unique entries [2:4] '''


# desired outcome:

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,1,1,2,2,2,],
                'Period':[1,2,3,1,2,3,],
                'Food':['Ham','Ham','Ham','Cheese','Cheese','Cheese',]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[3,3,3,4,4,4],
                'Period':[1,2,3,1,2,3,],
                'Food':['Egg','Egg','Egg','Bacon','Bacon','Bacon',]})

print(df1)
print(df2)
```

In this case, the DataFrame would be split at the end of every 2 sets of unique entries in the `df['Food']` column to create `df1` and `df2`. Best case scenario would be a loop that creates a new DataFrame for every x unique entries. Given the lack of info I can find, I'm unfortunately struggling to write even good pseudocode for that.

Comment: Your unique values are given by the **Food** column?

Comment: Yes. Thanks. I'll update the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let us try with `factorize` and `groupby`

```
n = 2
d = {x : y for x , y in df.groupby(df.Food.factorize()[0]//n)}
d[0]
Out[132]: 
   ID  Period    Food
0   1       1     Ham
1   1       2     Ham
2   1       3     Ham
3   2       1  Cheese
4   2       2  Cheese
5   2       3  Cheese
d[1]
Out[133]: 
    ID  Period   Food
6    3       1    Egg
7    3       2    Egg
8    3       3    Egg
9    4       1  Bacon
10   4       2  Bacon
11   4       3  Bacon
```

Comment: This is great, thanks! Would you mind explain in in a little more detail exactly what's going on here?

Comment: @JohnConor df.Food.factorize()[0]//2 this will first turn the unique count , then we div with 2 get the divisor， this will split the df every two unique value count per group

Answer (score 5):

Possible solution is the following:

```
# pip install pandas

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4],
                'Period':[1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,],
                'Food':['Ham','Ham','Ham','Cheese','Cheese','Cheese','Egg','Egg','Egg','Bacon','Bacon','Bacon',]})

dfs = [y for x, y in df.groupby('Food', as_index=False)]
```

Separated dfs can be accessed by list index (see below) or using loop:

```
dfs[0]
```

[image]

```
dfs[1]
```

[image]

```
and etc.
```

Comment: This does something slightly different by creating a df for each individual unique variable but is also very useful! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

We could use `groupby` + `ngroup` + `floordiv` to create groups; then use another `groupby` to separate:

```
out = [x for _, x in df.groupby(df.groupby('Food', sort=False).ngroup().floordiv(2))]
```

Output:

```
[   ID  Period    Food
0   1       1     Ham
1   1       2     Ham
2   1       3     Ham
3   2       1  Cheese
4   2       2  Cheese
5   2       3  Cheese,

    ID  Period   Food
6    3       1    Egg
7    3       2    Egg
8    3       3    Egg
9    4       1  Bacon
10   4       2  Bacon
11   4       3  Bacon]
```

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand, this may help:

```
for x in df['ID'].unique():
    print(df[df['ID']==x], '\n')
```

```
for x in df['Food'].unique():
    print(df[df['Food']==x], '\n')
```